# How to convert a cudf.core.dataframe.DataFrame into a pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: cudf

I have a cudf dataframe

```
type(pred)
> cudf.core.dataframe.DataFrame

print(pred)
>        action
1778378       0
1778379       1
1778381       1
1778383       0
1778384       0
...         ...
2390444       0
2390446       0
2390478       0
2390481       0
2390489       1
```

that I would like to convert to a `pandas.DataFrame()`. Though

```
pd.DataFrame(pred)
>       0
0  action
```

And just found the answer:

```
pred.to_pandas()
```

Comment: yup, `to_pandas()` will do the trick